# Understanding Python's import __main__

Tags: python, import

I have a file called `My_Scripts.py` running, which imports `field.py` and tries to execute the line `globals.BitRate()`. But I am getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BitRate'
```

What does `import __main__` mean in python? `My_Scripts.py` does not have a `def main()`.

`field.py`:

```
import __main__ as globals
globals.BitRate(..)
print globals
```

The `print globals` from `field.py` prints:

```
<module '__main__' from My_Scripts.py'>
```

Comment: If you're trying to import the `field` module, what made you think importing `__main__` would be a good idea? And why are you shadowing the `globals` built-in?

Answer (score 2):

Your `field.py`, for some reason, requires that the main program (in your case, `My_Scripts.py`) export a symbol called `BitRate`. Try adding

```
def BitRate(*args, **kw):
    pass
```

to your `My_Scripts.py`.

`import __main__` imports the main module, that is the one indicated on the python command line. When you run `python My_Scripts.py`, then `My_Scripts.py` becomes the main module. This is unrelated to whether any particular module implements `def main():...`.